# Report GET_ACCOUNTS permission in other app

Tags: android, permissions

I am actually preparing to release an app using the device google account to authenticate on Google App Engine server.

To do that, I need those permissions :

- USE_CREDENTIALS : obviously
- INTERNET : obviously
- GET_ACCOUNTS : to ask the user to select one of the google accounts registered on his phone.

My problem is with GET_ACCOUNTS : I think it's quite intrusive to ask this permission along with INTERNET : I would be able to get all his accounts (google, facebook, etc...) and send them to my server (I won't do that of course !). But I fear this permission may scare users, and they may not download my app...

I had the idea to report this permission to an other app, which wouldn't have INTERNET permission. This app would be called with an intent, and return only the account chosen by the user. And then, my main app don't need GET_ACCOUNTS anymore.

The source code is there : http://code.google.com/p/account-chooser/
It's quite simple (only one screen)

To send an intent to this app I use a utility library like IntentIntegrator from ZXing. If my "account chooser" app is not present on the device, it asks the user to download it from market.

What do you think about that ? Is it a good idea ? Am I right to bother the user with downloading a mysterious app he may not understand the usefulness ? Or should I just use GET_ACCOUNTS permission in my main app without questionning myself about privacy ?

Comment: I have not played with `AccountManager` yet. Are you saying that launching an activity via `newChooseAccountIntent()` requires `GET_ACCOUNTS`?

Comment: This method is only available from api lvl 14, and I use api lvl 8 :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So instead of just asking for the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission *within* your app, you plan to request it in *another* app and in turn *expose* that information to **any other** app on the device (via an intent).

Stick with asking for the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission *within* your app and be done with it. Speaking from experience, if an app I downloaded forced me to install yet another app *just* to get some functionality out of it, well.. you know what happens next :)

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I was going to do... And yes, it would be exposed to other apps via an intent, but it's the user who choose which account to expose with a confirmation (ok/cancel buttons). Anyway, I think I'll just change my mind and follow your advice.